# How to sent the response as 404 not found

Tags: node.js, security, web-hosting, request-headers, response-headers

For the host header injection attack, the response is coming as

```
<HTML>
 <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
 <body>
   <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
   <hr><center>nginx</center>
 </body>
</html>
```

How to change the response to 404 Not Found
The default Host is declared in the server and validation in the code is done like this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const host: any = req.headers.host;
  const url = new URL(config.app.baseUrl);
  const domain = url.hostname;
  console.log(domain,"domain");
  const allowedHosts = [domain + ":" + config.app.port]; 
  const allowedHosts = ['localhost:4000', 'testserver.com'];
  if (!allowedHosts.includes(host)) {
    res.status(HttpStatus.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST).send({ 
    ResponseMessage: "Invalid Host 
    header", IsError: true });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
  app.all("*", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.path.startsWith("/api")) {
     return res
    .status(HttpStatus.STATUS_FORBIDDEN)
    .send({ ResponseMessage: "Access denied", IsError: true });
    }
  });
```

Request headers are:-

```
GET /assets HTTP/1.1
Host: testserver.com
Cookie: i18next=en
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="109", "Not_A Brand";v="99"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
From: U2FsdGVkX1s1L2a3QELNbGz66lPBKVCYAI4iTEUYKW9a1y5Y=
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.5414.75 
Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://testserver.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: close
```

I don't know the reason please help me out...